# How do I use FTP_Implicit_SSL class to connect to Implicit SSL/TSL?

Tags: php, ftp

I need to connect to a FTP server with Implicit SSL/TLS

A quick Google and I found [this chaps wrapper class](https://gist.github.com/maxrice/4544344)

But there no demo on how to use it? I can't see from that how or where I specify the user name, password etc...

I'm sure it's easy but I just cannot see how to set them. If I run the following code I get errors straight away:

```
<?php
include "../objects/shared/ftp-implicit-ssl-tls.php";

$FTP_Implicit_SSL = new FTP_Implicit_SSL();
?>
```

Error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for FTP_Implicit_SSL::__construct(), called in C:\wamp\www_dev\ftp.php on line 4 and defined in C:\wamp\www\objects\shared\ftp-implicit-ssl-tls.php on line 35

Do I set the credentials in the class itself? Surely not!

Comment: Did you have a look at [`FTP_Implicit_SSL::__construct`](https://gist.github.com/maxrice/4544344#file-class-ftp-implicit-ssl-tls-php-L35) in the code you linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you read the class very carefully. When you create a new class you need to look for the [__construct() method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), as that's what gets called when you call `new class()`

```
/**
     * Connect to FTP server over Implicit SSL/TLS
     *
     *
     * @access public
     * @since 1.0
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $server
     * @param int $port
     * @param string $initial_path
     * @param bool $passive_mode
     * @throws Exception - blank username / password / port
     * @return \FTP_Implicit_SSL
     */
    public function __construct( $username, $password, $server, $port = 990, $initial_path = '', $passive_mode = false ) {
```

That first part in comments is called a [docblock](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html) and it tells you everything you need to know to instantiate the class with those arguments. So it would look something like this

```
$FTP_Implicit_SSL = new FTP_Implicit_SSL($username, $password, 'your.server.com');
```